# Для каждого объекта класса создать член типа QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Всем привет! Я пишу приложение на С++ в среде Qt Creator, в котором будет несколько окон. У меня имеется массив некоторых объектов, и я хочу, чтобы у каждого данного объекта среди приватных членов был член, наследуемый от класса QWidget. Т. е. чтобы у каждого объекта было свое окно с информацией о нем. Можно ли так сделать или просто перед каждым вызовом show из объекта обновлять информацию в окне, в соответствии с данными объекта? Или как-то создать массив объектов QWidget?
Надеюсь мой вопрос понятен. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Выглядит вопрос намного туманно. Приведите какой-то псевдокод, что-ли.

Comment: Что представляют собой эти объекты? Вам нужно, чтобы объекты умели выводить окно?

Comment: Вариант с просто обновлением данных выглядит проще и убедительней. Хотя не понятно что вам нужно.  Если вам нужно много одинаковых окон с разной информацией или вам нужно одно окно  изменяющейся информацией??